# AngularJS Dynamically adding tabs to a vertical tab table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am currently trying to make a dynamic vertical tab table in AngularJS. In other words, I would like for the user to add in their own tabs on the press of a button. I am aware of how to do this if the tabs are horizontal over the table but if the tabs are vertically on the right of the table, I have to put them in different divs. Im having a hard time relating the data from the tabs to the table content.

```
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div ng-show="view_tab == 'tab1'">
        Campaign Name:
        <input ng-model="tab1name">
        <br>Campaign Info:
        <br>This is tab 1 content

      </div>
      <div ng-show="view_tab == 'tab2'">
        Campaign Name:
        <input ng-model="tab2name">
        <br>Campaign Info:
        <br>This is tab 2 content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-pills" role="tablist" ng-init="view_tab = 'tab1'">
      <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab1'}">
        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')" href=""> Campaign: {{tab1name}}</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab2'}">
        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')" href=""> Campaign: {{tab2name}}</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab3'}">
        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')" href="">Add a Tab</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I'm aware that I need to use a ng-repeat and some kind of template to push onto an object holding all the table data. But I'm unclear of how to actually implement this. I have included a JSFiddle of the vertical tab table I am currently working with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/eRGT8/1032/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to create a array of all tabs and use `ng-repeat`

this is the tamplate

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-pills" role="tablist" ng-init="view_tab = 'tab1'">
<li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == $index}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs"> 
    <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab($index)" href=""> Campaign: {{tab.name}}</a>
 </li>
```

And this is the array:

```
$scope.tabs = [{
   name: ''
 }, {
    name: ''
}]
```

here is the full code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jekvu1br/